# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

im getting the Object reference not set to an instance of an object for line 43 and i cant figure out why, i have searched the web and cant seem to find the answer. i am new to C# and programming in general and trying to learn. if some one can help me out it would be great

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class ore 
        {
            public float Titan;
            public float Eperton;
        }

        ore b1 = null;
        ore b2 = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ore b2 = new ore();
            ore b1 = new ore();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float tempFloat;

            if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
            {
                b1.Titan = tempFloat; //line 43; where error happens
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float tempFloat;
            if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
            {
                b2.Eperton = tempFloat;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<ore> oreData = new List<ore>();
            oreData.Add(b1);
            oreData.Add(b2);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(fs, oreData);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: b1.Titan = tempFloat;   is line 43

Comment: This isn't the full code... It should work. Edit: Damn, missed that.

Comment: Vercas: it is the full code, see Rob's answer. The mistake is very subtle.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y7xCACbn   this is a pastebin link of the entire code just in case it didnt copy correctly

Comment: it compiles fine but when and number is added to the text box the error shows

Comment: @AUpadhyay: he does with the `TryParse`. Have a look at what `out` does.

Comment: this problem is solved a BIG thanks to all of you that helped me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming it's failing on any of the b1/b2 references.

```
ore b1 = null;
ore b2 = null;
```

Here you're declaring two private variables for your class

```
ore b2 = new ore();
ore b1 = new ore();
```

Here you're declaring two local variables for *that* method call. You're not altering the original variables. Change it to:

```
b2 = new ore();
b1 = new ore();
```

Comment: AWESOME okay that error is gone. i have a new issue however, the button is supposed to list ore and write it to a file called ore.dat in the programs directory. i ran the program and hit the save button BUT no new file in my project directory??

Answer (score 5):

You never assign the field `b1`. The `b1` you assign in the constructor is a local variable. Change the code in the constructor to this:

```
b2 = new ore();
b1 = new ore();
```

Answer (score 3):

change your constructor to this:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        b2 = new ore();
        b1 = new ore();
    }
```